# Unable to click the Quality button

Tags: python, selenium, automation, youtube

Any idea on how do I click the quality button as shown in the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pcbc3.png) using selenium in python.

I am only able to open the settings menu, Not any further.

My main aim is to automatically change the video quality. 
Thanks in advance!

```
list = driver.find_elements_by_name("ytp-settings-button")
list[0].click()
```

Answer (score 0):

All the operation are dynamic in nature, the use of explicit wait is very important in this case. As per my observation , by using given below steps could help you

1. click on setting button
2. wait for object visible of "Quality"
3. Once found object, then click on it
4. wait for object visible of "480P" (i.e. required pixel)
5. once available, click on it.

To get xpath of [quality](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MU4Uw.png) and [Pixel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qz8la.png) go to screenshot.

To stop the loading of element , check the parent tag in which the dynamic element appears and then right click on that tag and select "break on" then "subtree modification". This will stop the loading of website if any changes occur in that tag.

Comment: The problem with the screenshot of yours is that, IT is a label.... Hence Copying its X path doesn't work! I am also aware of the explicit wait thing... But the Xpath of the qualtiy BUTTON is the damn thing